# is it possible to make fixed ratingbar?

Tags: android

I am getting rating from the web and want to show the rating by ratingbar.

But my problem is rating of ratingbar is changing when I slide a ratingbar.

I want the rating is fixed and do not changed by user's touch.

is anybody able to limit control of ratingbar? How can I do that?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Use [`android:isIndicator="true"`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RatingBar.html#attr_android:isIndicator) in your layout or [`setIsIndicator(boolean isIndicator)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RatingBar.html#setIsIndicator%28boolean%29) from code to prevent user interaction with the RatingBar widget.

Quote from the docs:

> android:isIndicator - Whether this rating bar should only be an indicator (thus
>   non-changeable by the user).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it works the way you want... make the Rating bar not focussable and not clickable by set `setFocussableInTouchMode(false);`, and `setClickable(false);`